# ember-data model is not being deleted when transitioning a route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to delete a model when I leaving a route.  I am using the following in the route:

```
actions : {
    willTransition: function(transition){
        //Cleanup search model
        var model = this.modelFor('route1.index');
        model.deleteRecord();
        //At this point the model.get('isDeleted') = true
    }
}
```

From ember inspector when I have transitioned to my new route `route1.route2`, I can still see the model and its `isDeleted` property is now false.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you `willTransition` will be also called before you're entering the route, so you have to make sure that the transition's target is different from the current route:

```
if (transition.intent.name !== this.routeName)
```

Then, you can probably use something like:

```
var model = this.modelFor(this.routeName);
```

instead of manually type the route name.

How did you check that the model is not deleted? Maybe you created a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `save()` method after calling `deleteRecord()`

```
actions : {
   willTransition: function(transition){
        //Cleanup search model
        var model = this.modelFor('route1.index');
        model.deleteRecord();
        model.save();
    }
}
```

Or just use `model.destroyRecord();` as it does both